# Find the equation of the line tangent to the point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

[image]

Hello, I have been working on this problem and I have my work attached. I thought I got the right answer, but when I checked my answer I found that point P was not an inflection point of the equation after I found values of b and c. I don’t know where my mistake was so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please spare us your draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks correct to me, so you must have made some error in checking the solution. Differentiating $x^3+3x^2+3$ twice produces $6x+6$, which clearly vanishes at $x=-1$, just as you have in the lower-left corner.

Perhaps you’re thinking that the graph must “flatten out” at this point for it to be an inflection point, but all that’s required is that the curve go from being concave to convex, or vice-versa.

Comment: But when I graph this equation the point (-1,5) is not an inflection point. Can you also check this?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I made an error. Sorry about that.

Comment: How can you tell that it’s not an inflection point from looking at the graph? What do you think the definition of “inflection point” is?

Comment: I somehow confused the definition of an inflection point in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have
$$y'=3x^2+2bx$$
$$y''=6x+2b$$ we get
$$y''=0$$ if $$x=-\frac{b}{3}$$ since $$P(-1,5)$$ we get
$$b=3$$ and $$5=-1+27+c$$ so $$c=-21$$

Comment: How did you end up with $27$ from $3\cdot(-1)^2$?

Comment: I have used $$5=(-1)^3+b\times (-1)^2+c$$

Comment: So, you substituted $3$ (the value of $b$) instead of the correct $-1$ for $x$.

Comment: Oh sorry, i have made a misstake!

Comment: This is Right! I will correct this!

Comment: Even when c = 3 and b = 3 the inflection point stated in the problem is not the inflection point of the equation when c=3 and b=3. This is the problem I am having.

Comment: So we get $$c=3$$